# Trying to remove suffix, but can only remove extension

Tags: bash

My files are in a format of:

```
first_filename_R1_001.fastq.gz
first_filename_R2_001.fastq.gz
second_filename_R1_001.fastq.gz
second_filename_R2_001.fastq.gz
etc
```

I'm trying to pair the R1 and R2 versions of each group together in a script. However, I got stuck at removing the suffix.

```
for i in /directory/*_R1_*;do
echo "$i"
j=${i%"$R1_001.fastq.gz"}"R2_001.fastq.gz"
echo "$j"
done
```

What I would like to get:

```
/directory/first_filename_R1_001.fastq.gz
/directory/first_filename_R2_001.fastq.gz
...
```

What I am actually getting:

```
/directory/first_filename_R1_001.fastq.gz
/directory/first_filename_R1_001R2_001.fastq.gz
...
```

It seems that for some reason only the extension is removed. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: `"$R1_001.fastq.gz"` tries to expand a *variable named* `R1_001.fastq.gz` - if you want to remove a *fixed string* it should just be `${i%R1_001.fastq.gz}`

Comment: Will you always have just `foo_R1_001.fastq.gz` and `foo_R2_001.fastq.gz` or can you also have `_R1_002.fastq.gz` and `_R2_002.fastq.gz` and so on?

Comment: @steeldriver Perfect! That makes sense and it worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great! Since this was just a typo and you've now fixed it, I closed the question as non-reproducible.